# How to export wide gantt chart to JPG or PNG in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

When I try to export a haghchart Gantt to JPA or PNG based-on blow options, I cannot export the wide one, so it's not appropriate for printing.

```
exporting: 
{
     enabled: true,
     scale: 3,
     with: 2048
}
```

How is it possible to export a wide picture of Gantt chart?

Comment: It seems that there is a small mistake in your config `with`, but it should be `width`. Try to correct it and test if it fits your requirements. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.width

Comment: I've corrected it, but I cannot see any difference @SebastianWędzel

Comment: Zarei it seems that the `exporting.width` option works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/he094a7p/ also consider to use the `scale` property: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d4k0ue2h/